# Extract and plot condition information from csv in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

**INPUT:** I have a CSV file with a lot of information about population living in Barcelona. I want to represented in a histogram or maybe in a plot, the total population vs district. The field of district is repeated x times...

[image]

The second column for my it is not important to show in the histogram or plat, only in x-axies the number of district and y-axies the total people that live in this district.

````
```{r}
# Allows to define graphics efficiently, elegantly and simply.
library(ggplot2)
v_file <- "../../dataset.csv"
data <- read.csv(file=v_file, sep=',', header = TRUE)
population <- data[2:73, 1:3]
population
dput(population[, ,])
```
````

and the dput shows to my:

```
structure(list(Dte. = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "10", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "BARCELONA"), class = "factor"), Barris = structure(c(2L, 
13L, 24L, 35L, 46L, 57L, 68L, 73L, 74L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 36L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 
66L, 67L, 69L, 70L, 71L), .Label = c("", "1. el Raval", "10. Sant Antoni", 
"11. el Poble Sec - AEI Parc Montjuïc", "12. la Marina del Prat Vermell - AEI Zona Franca", 
"13. la Marina de Port", "14. la Font de la Guatlla", "15. Hostafrancs", 
"16. la Bordeta", "17. Sants - Badal", "18. Sants", "19. les Corts", 
"2. el Barri Gòtic", "20. la Maternitat i Sant Ramon", "21. Pedralbes", 
"22. Vallvidrera, el Tibidabo i les Planes", "23. Sarrià", "24. les Tres Torres", 
"25. Sant Gervasi - la Bonanova", "26. Sant Gervasi - Galvany", 
"27. el Putxet i el Farró", "28. Vallcarca i els Penitents", 
"29. el Coll", "3. la Barceloneta", "30. la Salut", "31. la Vila de Gràcia", 
"32. el Camp d'en Grassot i Gràcia Nova", "33. el Baix Guinardó", 
"34. Can Baró", "35. el Guinardó", "36. la Font d'en Fargues", 
"37. el Carmel", "38. la Teixonera", "39. Sant Genís dels Agudells", 
"4. Sant Pere, Santa Caterina i la Ribera", "40. Montbau", "41. la Vall d'Hebron", 
"42. la Clota", "43. Horta", "44. Vilapicina i la Torre Llobeta", 
"45. Porta", "46. el Turó de la Peira", "47. Can Peguera", "48. la Guineueta", 
"49. Canyelles", "5. el Fort Pienc", "50. les Roquetes", "51. Verdun", 
"52. la Prosperitat", "53. la Trinitat Nova", "54. Torre Baró", 
"55. Ciutat Meridiana", "56. Vallbona", "57. la Trinitat Vella", 
"58. Baró de Viver", "59. el Bon Pastor", "6. la Sagrada Família", 
"60. Sant Andreu", "61. la Sagrera", "62. el Congrés i els Indians", 
"63. Navas", "64. el Camp de l'Arpa del Clot", "65. el Clot", 
"66. el Parc i la Llacuna del Poblenou", "67. la Vila Olímpica del Poblenou", 
"68. el Poblenou", "69. Diagonal Mar i el Front Marítim del Poblenou", 
"7. la Dreta de l'Eixample", "70. el Besòs i el Maresme", "71. Provençals del Poblenou", 
"72. Sant Martí de Provençals", "73. la Verneda i la Pau", 
"8. l'Antiga Esquerra de l'Eixample", "9. la Nova Esquerra de l'Eixample"
), class = "factor"), TOTAL = c(47986L, 16240L, 15101L, 22923L, 
32048L, 51651L, 44246L, 42512L, 58315L, 38412L, 40358L, 1151L, 
30622L, 10422L, 15949L, 18561L, 24047L, 41244L, 46104L, 23980L, 
12117L, 4689L, 25106L, 16660L, 25909L, 47753L, 29617L, 15615L, 
7428L, 13207L, 50885L, 34431L, 25734L, 9020L, 36538L, 9390L, 
31583L, 11634L, 6971L, 5171L, 5792L, 611L, 26743L, 25618L, 25046L, 
15506L, 2233L, 15247L, 6863L, 15648L, 12368L, 26398L, 7271L, 
2859L, 10369L, 1379L, 10006L, 2539L, 12582L, 57223L, 29031L, 
14141L, 22171L, 38371L, 27089L, 15204L, 9404L, 33931L, 13710L, 
22893L, 20649L, 26187L)), .Names = c("Dte.", "Barris", "TOTAL"
), row.names = 2:73, class = "data.frame")
```

**OUTPUT:** A histogram with ggplot2 library that show in x-axies the number of district and in y-axies the sum of TOTAL field that belongs to the district.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
 df%>%
  group_by(Dte.)%>%
  summarise(total=sum(TOTAL))%>%
  mutate(Dte.=as.numeric( as.character(Dte.) ))%>%
  arrange(Dte.)%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(Dte.),y=total))+geom_col()+
  labs(x="Dte.",y="TOTAL")
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that RStudio didn't recognize the group_by

Comment: Error in group_by(Dte.) : could not find function "group_by"

Comment: Add `library(tidyverse)`

Comment: `%>%` meant sequential actions. this one make your code more readeble and simple

Comment: I installed the package for tidyverse, and when I run the project... "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘broom’"

Comment: ok, you need this one `install.packages("devtools");devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyverse")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182042/discussion-between-jyjek-and-anna-castan).

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  group_by(Dte.) %>% 
  summarise(Population = sum(TOTAL)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Dte., y = Population)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: For bonus points it would be great to include some explanation of this code, and why this solves the OP's problem.

Comment: why are you using tidyverse?

Comment: The tidyverse package contains ggplot, as well as dplyr which has the group_by and summarise functions.  For more info, I highly recommend [R For Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html)